# Determine if a rect is visible inside window

Tags: winapi, window, visible, rect

I would like to determine if a rect inside a window is completly visible.

I have found RectVisible, but that function determines if any part of the rect is visible, I want to know if the entire rect is visible.

Is there any function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the system clipping region (the visible region of a window) into a region by using [`GetRandomRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144918%28VS.85%29.aspx). Read more about the 'system region' [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/cliprgnguide.aspx). Then, offset that region since it is in screen coordinates (the article I linked has an example). After that, create a region from your rectangle with [`CreateRectRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183514%28VS.85%29.aspx) and combine the parts of your 'rectangle region' with those that are not part of the 'system region': that is calling [`CombineRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183465%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) passing the rectangle region as the first region, and the system region as the second region, and `RGN_DIFF` as the `fnCombineMode`. If the result is `NULLREGION` then your rectangle is fully visible - it is not fully or partially covered by any window (top level or not), or it is not fully or partially off-screen.

All in all, there's a probability that you're approaching your problem the wrong way around. If you've told what you've been trying to achieve someone could probably suggest a simpler approach.

Comment: On Windows 7 'system region' always is exactly the same as rectangle region, even if window is closed by other windows or off-screen.

Answer (score 2):

Use [PtVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162890%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on each corner of the rectangle.

> The PtVisible function determines
>   whether the specified point is within
>   the clipping region of a device
>   context.

Comment: That will work most of the times, but you can't be sure something isn't covering the inside of the rect. A window smaller then the rect could be placed ontop of the window i need to check.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do a simple comparison using the coordinates of the window and the rectangle.

Check the rectangle's left ordinate is to the right of the Window's left border; the right ordinate is to the left of the Window's right border; and similar for top and bottom?

The only wrinkle might be if you are using both logical and physical coordinates, in which case you will need to perform a transformation.

Answer (score 1):

All the functions that dealt with clip rectangles and point visibility broke with Windows Vista's new desktop composition feature.  The functions will work fine on Windows XP and earlier, and on Windows 7 with Aero/Desktop Composition turned off, but otherwise, they will always claim that the entire window is visible.