# How to check if my window gets hidden/visible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi, opengl

If i press the "show desktop" button in Windows7, my program will still think its not minimized, and if i press `WIN+D` while my program is focused, only then my program will catch this minimize command. How can i check for 100% sure that my program is visible or not?

Here is my main loop:

```
while(!done){
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT){
            done = TRUE;
        }else{
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }else if(active){
        render();
    }
}
```

**Edit3:** Is this good? looks like its working:

```
case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
{
        flags = ((PWINDOWPOS)lParam)->flags;
        if((flags & 0x8000) && (flags & SWP_NOCOPYBITS) && (flags & SWP_FRAMECHANGED)){
            active = !(flags & SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        }
        if((flags & 0x1000) && (flags & 0x0800) && (flags & SWP_NOMOVE) && (flags & SWP_NOSIZE)){
            active = 1;
        }
}
case WM_ACTIVATE:
{
    active = !HIWORD(wParam);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's erasing things when you hide the window?

Comment: @Cody Gray, i dont know what you mean... can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve. Why do you care if the window is visible? When its contents need to be redrawn, Windows will send you a `WM_PAINT` message, and you can respond appropriately. If you're doing anything else, you're vastly overengineering.

Comment: @Cody, the problem is that my program rendering loop will keep running if i press that "show desktop" button... because it doesnt tell me it got hidden.

Comment: Why in the world does your program have a "rendering loop"? What does that do? Why is your program different from every other program in the known world? And more importantly, why is this information not included in your question?

Comment: @Cody, i use openGL to render, i dont understand how this has anything to do with my problem. I put winapi tag on purpose: this should be something to do with window messages handling. I doubt my program is that much of different from others since many people just copypaste nehe tutorials just like i did. So... please understand.

Comment: Yes, it has everything to do with Windows message handling. You need the `WM_PAINT` message. That's your cue that some part of the window has become visible again, and you need to redraw its contents.

Comment: If you just "copypasted" some tutorial from the internet, no wonder you're having problems. Read through the OpenGL Red Book so that you actually have understanding about what your program does.

Comment: @Cody, i added my main loop code. how should i implement the `WM_PAINT` check there so the `active` will be false when my window isnt visible and true if it is?

Comment: @Cody Gray:  There are many types of programs that do real-time rendering (3D animation, arcade-style games, video players, etc.) that cannot rely on the timing of the Windows event loop for paint events.  It's perfectly normal for these types of apps to pause their rendering loops when the window is minimized or hidden.

Comment: @Adrian: Yes, it's easier to answer questions when you have all of the information. Notice that we only learned in a much later comment that this was an OpenGL application. There's obviously no reason for a normal application to do this. The paint messages are sent whenever things need to be painted. There's not going to be anything wrong with the timing when you rely on them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WM_ACTIVATE is sent when another window becomes active.  When you say show desktop, no other window becomes active, so technically, your app is still active, even though it has been minimized.

You probably want to watch for [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You can look at the flags to see what type of position event it was, or you can check [IsIconic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IsWindowVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) whenever the window position changes.

Comment: hmm, i think this will be the right answer, but it would be more helpful to know what these codes actually mean (none of the codes i received were on the website you linked). look at my code i posted, if theres anything to fix.

Comment: The WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED message gets a pointer (via the LPARAM) to a WINDOWPOS structure.  The documentation for that structure has the meanings of the flags.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632612(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: see the code i posted... none of the codes i found are on that page. (or am i just blind?)

Comment: looks like i was just plain stupid, but now i know how to read those. the 0x1803 is a mystery; i cant find 0x1000 or 0x0800 in the docs at all. so im thinking is it ok to use the current code i have?

Comment: You could skip trying to decode the flags and just check IsIconic and IsWindowVisible each time this message comes along.  It's an infrequent message, so you're not really polling, and the message will come at the times you care about (when your window becomes hidden or visible).

Comment: Also, there is [WM_SHOWWINDOW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, which is sent to window before its visibility state changes.

Answer (score 5):

There are a variety of potential functions that may get you the information you need depending on exactly what you want to do:

- [GetForegroundWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) : Gets the window the user is currently "working" with. You could use this if you only wanted to draw things when a user is using your application but not another one.
- [GetActiveWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646292%28VS.85%29.aspx) : Returns the active window within the calling thread which is probably not what you want. This might be useful if you wish to enable/disable drawing depending on which window was active within your own application.
- [GetFocus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294%28VS.85%29.aspx) : Returns the window with the current keyboard focus in the calling thread. Probably not what you want and use GetForegorundWindow() instead.
- [IsWindowVisible()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633530%28VS.85%29.aspx): Returns whether the show/hide flag of the window is set to visible. This doesn't actually tell you whether the window is actually visible on the screen.
- [GetTopWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633514%28VS.85%29.aspx): Tells you the highest window in the z-order but not whether it actually has the focus/foreground. It may be possible for your window to be focused/activate/foreground but not have the highest z-order (I think anyways).

From your comments, however, you seem to actually want to see if there is at least one pixel of your window actually visible on the screen. For that I would probably use the technique mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071810/determine-if-a-rect-is-visible-inside-window) using the strangely named [GetRandomRgn()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144918%28VS.85%29.aspx) although a simpler check may be to use [GetClipBox()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144865%28VS.85%29.aspx) and check the return code for `NULLREGION`.

Comment: its not important to know if there is ANY pixels visible, but just that if its minimized or not. the WIN+D button and "show desktop" button didnt give the minimize message. check my latest edit for the code im using now. see if theres something to improve?

Comment: Ahh, I see. The `IsIconic()` function should give you the minimized state and the `WM_SIZE` message should be passed on to your top level window when changing the minimize/maximize state. If you keep your current edit using `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` you may wish to not use the hard-coded constants but explicitly check for the flags (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Otherwise it may work most of the time but not all the time depending on the exact flags passed into WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED.

Comment: the link you (and someone else) keep pasteing to me doesnt have those codes explained which i found out to work for me :|

Comment: Scroll down the page a bit and look under the flags parameter.

Comment: NO, there is not. check yourself: 0x8130 0x1803 0x8120 none of those found there.

Comment: As is standard on Windows the flags parameter is a bitwise combination of the individual flags. For example: `0x8130 = 0x8000 | 0x0100 | 0x0020 | 0x0010`. The 0x0010 flag is SWP_NOACTIVATE for example and I'm not sure what 0x8000 is. So, if you were specifically interested in SWP_NOACTIVATE you could check for it like `(Flags & SWP_NOACTIVATE) != 0`.

Comment: looks like 0x1803 is still a mystery. cant find 0x1000 or 0x0800 in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

With Windows 8/10, there's another window visibility flag which is separate from IsWindowVisible.  Check DwmGetWindowAttribute and the DWMWA_CLOAKED attribute.

Additionally, windows can be semitransparent, and GetLayeredWindowAttributes can tell you what the alpha level of a window is.

Answer (score 0):

IsWindowVisible tells you if your window is visible. GetTopWindow tells you if it is the uppermost one in the Z order.

Comment: do you know a method that doesnt require me to calling that function every now and then? like the `case WM_ACTIVATE:` thing i use now.

Comment: not to mention i tried that IsWindowVisible() and it doesnt seem to catch the `WIN+D` either. (unless my program is currently focused)

Comment: *"GetTopWindow tells you if it is the uppermost one in the Z order."* - That's not what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633514.aspx) says: *"Examines the Z order of the child windows associated with the specified parent window and retrieves a handle to the **child window** at the top of the Z order."* The OP is asking about a top-level window.

Answer (score 0):

Try WM_ACTIVATEAPP.

wParam will be false if a window from any other app is getting focus. This includes pressing the "show desktop" button.

Comment: but that would mean i would stop rendering even if theres just some small window on top of my rendering window? i dont want to do that. only when its completely hidden, then i want to stop rendering.

Comment: True, sorta. It does give you a place to hook in a call to a function like IsWindowVisible. Actually, I don't see that anyone has mentioned a simple WM_SIZE message. I just checked and my apps get WM_SIZE when "show desktop" is pressed.